# How to correctly access parent form's field/s from inline form clean method during Update

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

I am a little perplexed. Using CreateView, When I try to `get` the **data** of a field in the parent table's form from the (child table's) inline form's clean method I can do that:

```
def clean(self):
    super(CreateMyItemsForm, self).clean()
    cleaned_data = super(CreateMyItemsForm, self).clean()
    var_date = self.data.get('valid_to_date')    #   NOTE: **valid_to_date** is a field in the parent table
```

However, during **update** (using UpdateView) the same method fails.

**Why?** What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.